# set direction attribute in Material input

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a standard input which I set the `dir` attribute according to a dynamic value (in addition to some other attributes).
here is how it works perfectly.

```html
  <input 
    [dir]="inputAlignDirection" 
    [id]="'firstName'+i" 
    [(ngModel)]="parent.firstName" 
    class="form-control input-lg" 
    [attr.aria-describedby]="'lblfirstName'+i" 
    pattern="^[a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF ]+$" 
    #firstName="ngModel" 
    [required]="i == 0"
    [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
    />
```

Now, I'd like to replace this input with a Material input, but not sure how to set all the attributes.
This is what I have tried but it doesn't work as expected.

```html
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<mat-label >{{selectedLanguage.firstName}}</mat-label>
<input  matInput placeholder= "{{selectedLanguage.firstName}}" [dir]="inputAlignDirection"  [(ngModel)]="parent.firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF ]+$" #firstName="ngModel" 
[required]="i == 0"
[ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What is the issue directional directive not working?

Comment: not sure. I'm not getting an exception. it just doesn't work

Comment: Ca you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Please [check out here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqv6bu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the minimal example of use `dir directive` on input

```js
inputAlignDirectionRTL: Direction = "rtl";
inputAlignDirectionLTL: Direction = "ltr";
```

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>inputAlignDirection: {{inputAlignDirectionRTL}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [dir]="inputAlignDirectionRTL"/>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>inputAlignDirection: {{inputAlignDirectionLTL}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [dir]="inputAlignDirectionLTL"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

According with [dir direcive source code](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/161a770de31fd66d3be41ab5334903c71c72ba93/src/cdk/bidi/dir.ts#L48) only accept a [type `Direction`](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/bidi/directionality.ts#L13) its value could be `rtl` or `ltr`

Comment: actually `inputAlignDirectionRTL` is acting like `ltr` in your stackblitz example. They both `ltr`

Comment: Mmm really? I have checked again and it's writtring in "reverse form". For example try to press delete and supr. It works different

Comment: you need to add it to ```<mat-form-field>``` tag.